# How i can get assosiative array from this $_POST result

Tags: php, arrays, post

can anyone help me to get array from this example?

```
   <div>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[][link]" value="site.com/1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[][img]" value="site.com/a1.img">
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[][link]" value="site.com/2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[][img]" value="site.com/a2.img">
    </div>
```

I want to get the assosiative array from this post results as

```
$post_results=array("link"=>site.com/1,"img"=>site.com/a1.img),
array("link"=>site.com/2,"img"=>site.com/a2.img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solve my problem because i have more than 30 combo input values and add them to assosiative array

```
 $array = $_POST['extracheckbox'];
    $newArray = array();
    foreach (array_keys($array) as $fieldKey) {
        foreach ($array[$fieldKey] as $key=>$value) {
            $newArray[$key][$fieldKey] = $value;
        }
    } 
var_dump($newArray);
```

results:

```
array[40]{
array('link'=>'site.com/1','img'=>site.com/a1.img),
array('link'=>'site.com/2','img'=>site.com/a2.img),
array('link'=>'site.com/3','img'=>site.com/a3.img),
array('link'=>'site.com/4','img'=>site.com/a4.img),
...};
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for comment i update my answer for another users

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[link]" value="site.com/1"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox[img]" value="site.com/a1.img"><br />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox2[link]" value="site.com/2"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="extracheckbox2[img]" value="site.com/a2.img"><br />
</div>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

result is:

```
Array
(
    [extracheckbox] => Array
        (
            [link] => site.com/1
            [img] => site.com/a1.img
        )

    [extracheckbox2] => Array
        (
            [link] => site.com/2
            [img] => site.com/a2.img
        )

)
```